# Accepting integer main arguments then using them to declare an array, issue with constantness?

Tags: c++, arrays, command-line-arguments

My main accepts command line arguments (which happen to be all ints) and then I need to create an array on the stack with it.

```
int main(int ragc, char *argv[]) {
```

Internet makes it seem like the convention is char*, is it possible to accept an int* instead since my command line arguments are only going to be integers?

Secondly, I need to declare this using 2 of the arguments:

```
 char databuf[nbufs][bufsize]; // where nbufs * bufsize = 1500
```

but the compiler is yelling at me that nbufs and bufsize need to have a constant value. Unfortunately they have to be ints I accept as command line arguments so how would they be constant values?

```
int main(int ragc, char *argv[]) {
    int nbufs = atoi(argv[3]); //grabs the nbufs
    int bufsize = atoi(argv[4]); //grabs the bufsize
    char databuf[nbufs][bufsize]; //where nbufs * bufsize = 1500
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `main` has arguments, then the second argument needs to be an array of `char*`s (or `const char*`s). This is just how it's defined in the spec. Intuitively, there's no guarantee that the command-line arguments must be integers; someone could run your program with a text argument, and it would be unclear whose job it would be to report the error (the OS, or your program)?

Second, in C++, you cannot declare arrays whose dimensions are non-constant. C allows you to do this (they're called variable-length arrays) and in C++1y (the next release of C++) this will likely be supported, but currently you cannot do this in C++. To fix this, instead use a `std::vector` of `std::vector`s, like this:

```
std::vector<std::vector<char>> databufs(nbufs, std::vector<char>(bufsize));
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why does the g++ compiler in Linux not care if I give non-constant array dimensions?

Comment: @MilanNovaković `g++` supports variable-length arrays in C++ as a compiler extension. It's not technically valid C++ and won't necessarily compile on other compilers.

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to accept an int* instead since my command line arguments are only going to be integers?

No, it is not possible: the standard dictates that the individual parameters are `char*`. Your use of `atoi` is perfectly valid for what you did.

> they have to be ints I accept as command line arguments so how would they be constant values?

They cannot be constant values, so you need to use dynamic allocation. Since this is C++, a better choice would be a vector of strings; however, `char**` is also possible:

```
char **dataBuf = new char*[nbufs];
for (int i = 0; i != nbufs ; i++) {
    dataBuf[i] = new char[bufsize];
}
// Use dataBuf here
...
// Now free its memory
for (int i = 0; i != nbufs ; i++) {
    delete[] dataBuf[i];
}
delete[] dataBuf;
```

Note: C99 does allow for variable-sized arrays; g++ allows these too, as an extension. You should be careful using extensions, however, because they make your program less portable.

Comment: Once we are don we should also free/release the memory.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be a `char*` because a `char*` can represent any possible value, but if it were `int/int*` your range of input is limited to numbers. I believe that's why the standard chose to define it using `char*`.